# Permissions for appdomain to run Ironpython in a sandbox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, permissions, ironpython, appdomain

Hey guys I'm trying to figure out what permissions I need to allow me to run ironpython in an appdomain but deny read and write privileges as well as internet privileges.

Here is my IronPython class:

```
public class PBLPython
{

    private static ScriptEngine pyEngine;
    private static ScriptRuntime pyRuntime;
    public ScriptScope pyScope { get; private set; }

    public PBLPython(String [] args)
    {

        String pyCodePath = "PATH";

        pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
        pyScope = pyEngine.CreateScope();
        dynamic Scope = pyScope;

        Scope.appy = this;

        pyEngine.ExecuteFile(pyCodePath, pyScope);

        foreach (String s in args)
        {
            pyEngine.Execute(s, pyScope);
        }

    } 
}
```

and here is my class that creates the appdomain

```
class PythonDomain
{
    private static AppDomain pyDomain;
    public PythonDomain()
    {

        AppDomain root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        String pyCodePath = @"PATH";
        String AppCodePath = @"PATH";
        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = AppCodePath;

        Evidence e = new Evidence();

        e.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.Intranet));
        e.AddHostEvidence(new ApplicationDirectory(AppCodePath));


        System.Security.PermissionSet ps =
            new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
        ps.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, pyCodePath));
        ps.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, AppCodePath));
        ps.AddPermission(new UIPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

        PermissionSet permSet = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(e);

        StrongName[] fullTrustAssemblies = new StrongName[5];
        fullTrustAssemblies[0] = typeof(PBLPython).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
        fullTrustAssemblies[1] = typeof(ScriptEngine).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
        fullTrustAssemblies[2] = typeof(ScriptRuntime).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
        fullTrustAssemblies[3] = typeof(ScriptScope).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
        fullTrustAssemblies[4] = 

        pyDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("PythonDomain", e, setup, ps, fullTrustAssemblies);

        pyDomain.ExecuteAssemblyByName(@"ConsoleApplication1", @"print('hellz yea')");

        AppDomain.Unload(pyDomain);



    }
```

Right now I get a generic security exception because of this line of code in my ironpython

```
Scope.appy = this;
```

if I change it to something that I haven't created like say Object it works perfectly. Can someone point out to me what permission I'm missing or is what I'm trying to do just not possible?